# How to call two classes inside runApp method in flutter

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I'm working with android flutter framework. I want to call two classes inside `runApp();` i tried but not getting.

```
void main(){
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    title: "Hello world",
    home: new demo1(), //like this i want to call here demo2
  ));
}

class demo1 extends StatalessWidget {
  //code here
}
class demo2 extends StatalessWidget {
  //code here
}
```

Can anyone suggest me? How should I do?

Comment: Your question is still not very clear.  What do you actually want to achieve?  Do you want, based on a parameter to either call demo1 or demo2, for example?

Comment: @boeledi I want to call demo1 and demo2 in main();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you intent to do. I'm guessing you want to show the two Widgets `demo1` and `demo2` together. In that case you can use [`Column`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Column-class.html).

```
void main(){
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    title: "Hello world",
    home: new Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        demo1(),
        demo2(),
      ],
    ),
  ));
}
```

There are many other options to layout the screen, have a look at the [Layout Widgets](https://flutter.io/widgets/layout/) section.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to call classes contidionally you can use turnery operator like below?

```
    void main(){
    bool condition = true;

      runApp(new MaterialApp(
        title: "Hello world",
        home:condition? demo1():demo2(), //like this i want to call here demo2
      ));
    }

    class demo1 extends StatalessWidget {
      //code here
    }
    class demo2 extends StatalessWidget {
      //code here
    }
```